# How do I make a Discord bot say something after anything is typed in chat?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, chatbot, discord.js

So I'm working on a spam bot for Discord.
Well, it's not really a *spam* bot, I just want it to reply to anything that is messaged in the chat (other than messages sent from other bots). How would I make this work? I can't find this anywhere else so I might as well ask here.

Also, no, I don't have any code other than the generic import commands and a couple logs to the console.

Comment: https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/

Comment: That guide is just for a bot that will respond to a certain message. I'm looking for code to make a bot respond to ANY message.

Comment: Then remove the logic where it checks what message to respond to, and make it respond to anything. You have to make an attempt...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how fast the messages are coming in, you'll possibly get ratelimited.

To get it to ignore other bot users you can use:

```
if(message.author.bot) return;
```

Then to just reply to any message that comes in, you would just handle the `message` event, like you would normally, but with no conditionals if you want it to reply to every message.

```
<Client>.on('message', message =>  {
    //handle reply
});
```

Comment: So how would I make it so that different messages would be replied at random?

Comment: @ConeyIsland use some NLP engine like amazon lex, dialogflow, rasa, luis etc

Comment: You could use NLP as suggested by Sid, although you could also have an array of phrases that you just randomly pick from and send, that way you have a little more control over what is said, although depending on which NLP engine you use, you can also have a lot of control over it.